# Best way to create interactive 3d rooms with Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, adobe-illustrator

Just after some quick advice.  I want to create an interactive animated flash music website that involves the user being able to wander around a rehersal room and interact with objects.

Can anyone recommend a good 3d tool to use along with Flash.  Ideally something that I can use Illustrator tpo draw the room/objects, but not essential.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would use illustrator to create 3d assets, but I think [papervision](http://dev.papervision3d.org/about/) looks like your best bet.

Otherwise you could use [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) instead of flash. You would get a much better result from Unity.

Comment: Illustrator can create 3D stuff, but I don't know if you can export it as a model... +1 for Unity-- it requires a different plugin but is much more feature filled and is suited better for 3D.

Comment: @Andrew M - I agree, although not many people have the Unity3D plugin (or are bothered to install it since it is not a household name as yet). It seems like the next Flash Player release will be have 3D gpu support so it should become less of an issue in the future. I guess there is also WebGL, although again it has its own issues.

Comment: The major advantage to Unity (and disadvantage of Flash and WebGL) is the tooling. Unity is so great and popular as a tool, because it does a fantastic job at what is was designed to do from scratch, 3D. Flash will never be "great" at 3D because the tools will never have anything on Unity for everything 3D. Doesn't matter what APIs Adobe introduce to ActionScript.

Answer (score 0):

Another 3D engine for Flash is [Away3D](http://away3d.com/). I mention it because Eminem's Relapse album website was built with it and from the sounds of things is simlar to what you are trying to achieve http://www.therelapse.com/#/?room=entrance - in saying so the site could be built with papervision too.